# Fortran Printing Diamond w/ Question Mark

Tags: fortran, fortran90, aix

I am running Fortran 90 on AIX. I'm not sure if this is a compatibility issue or not. I am trying to print a character string to the screen containing the last two characters of the current year (ex: it's 2016 and I want 16) and the output is displaying a black diamond with a question mark inside of it. What does that indicate/represent?

```
CHARACTER ( LEN=4 ) :: year_str

print *, "year_str(3:4) is: ", year_str(3:4)

Output:
period_year_str(3:4) is: ��
```

Comment: that is used to replace an unknown or unrepresentable character

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to set `year_str` to a value.

Comment: I am using existing code I did not write, and while I have not defined year_str here I believe it is defined elsewhere in another piece of code. But perhaps that is the problem. I have tried to grep for year_str and could not find what it was equal to...

Comment: @OmerJanjua is this because `year_str` has not been defined?

Comment: Try inserting the line `year_str = '2016'` just before the `print` statement and see what happens.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yep, that solved the issue. Worked exactly how I wanted it to after defining the string. Good to know.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for better visibility. Fortran 90 is just one specific (and old) version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous users commented, the black diamond represents an unknown character. This is because `year_str` was not properly defined.